# Voting indicator state is not reinstated when trying to remove a vote on a deleted post

Tags: bug, design, deleted-answers

If you try to remove a vote on a deleted post, you will get the "this post has been deleted" popup and the vote count will be reset back to what it was before you tried to rescind your vote, but the orange marker indicating your vote will not be reinstated until you reload the page.

(I assume this also happens with upvotes, I have only tested it on downvotes.)

Comment: Asked [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114101/glitch-when-trying-to-vote-on-deleted-answers), closed as dup of this [other Q](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44137/vote-arrow-not-reset-when-attempting-to-undo-vote-on-locked-post) which is marked [status-completed]... ([Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97057/hide-voting-arrows-on-deleted-posts))

Answer (score -2):

Since votes on deleted posts aren't counted in rep calc or for anything else, I don't think it matters.

Comment: Surely contradictions in the user interface are worthy of correction?

Comment: Yeah, probably.